# jQuery ajax does not work with window on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this `jquery` code. This code is working well, but when I put this code into window onload, it shows me nothing. Why is this happening? Does ajax not work with window onload?

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    let catId = searchParams.get('catId')
    let searchText = searchParams.get('SearchText');
    let catName = searchParams.get('catName');
    let nextPage = Number(searchParams.get('page'));
    let newUrl = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/glosearch/api/product?CatId=' + catId +'&SearchText=' + searchText + '&catName=' + catName + 'SortType=default&page=' + nextPage + '&isrefine=y&';
    console.log(newUrl)
    
    let fortest = $('.product-pagination-wrap').text();
    console.log(fortest);
    
    $.ajax({
        url: newUrl ,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: $.getJSON( newUrl, function( data ) {
            console.log(data)
        }),

        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
           console.log(xhr.status);
           console.log(error);
           }
       });  
    });
});
```

Comment: can you try using `$(document).ready(function(){
    // Ajax Code Here
});`

Comment: i need to use onload not document.ready

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, but you have a syntax error in it. You have an extra closing syntax `});` at the bottom of the code. Please remove it. The code will start to work.

Check this working fiddle -

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
    let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    let catId = searchParams.get('catId')
    let searchText = searchParams.get('SearchText');
    let catName = searchParams.get('catName');
    let nextPage = Number(searchParams.get('page'));
    let newUrl = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/glosearch/api/product?CatId=' + catId +'&SearchText=' + searchText + '&catName=' + catName + 'SortType=default&page=' + nextPage + '&isrefine=y&';
    console.log(newUrl)
    
    let fortest = $('.product-pagination-wrap').text();
    console.log(fortest);
    
    $.ajax({
        url: newUrl ,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: $.getJSON( newUrl, function( data ) {
            console.log(data)
        }),

        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
           console.log(xhr.status);
           console.log(error);
           }
       });  
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$(function(){ 

  let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  let catId = searchParams.get('catId')
  let searchText = searchParams.get('SearchText');
  let catName = searchParams.get('catName');
  let nextPage = Number(searchParams.get('page'));
  let newUrl = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/glosearch/api/product?CatId=' + catId +'&SearchText=' + searchText + '&catName=' + catName + 'SortType=default&page=' + nextPage + '&isrefine=y&';
  console.log(newUrl)

  let fortest = $('.product-pagination-wrap').text();


  $.ajax({
      url: newUrl ,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: $.getJSON( newUrl, function( data ) {
          console.log(data)
      }),
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
         console.log(xhr.status);
         console.log(error);
       }
    });  
});
```